# Simple Snake Game

Tags: c++, c++11, game, sfml, snake-game

I was working on this game for while and I have made it for education purposes by using SFML. The game works fine but I would like to know how I can improve it.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

namespace
{
    const sf::Vector2f WindowSize(640, 480);
    constexpr auto BlockSize = 16.f;
    constexpr auto SnakeSpeed = 5.f;
    const auto TimeStep = sf::seconds(1 / SnakeSpeed);

    auto randomEngine()
    {
        std::array<std::mt19937::result_type, std::mt19937::state_size> seed_data;
        thread_local std::random_device source;
        std::generate(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data), std::ref(source));
        std::seed_seq seeds(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
        thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
        return seeded_engine;
    }

    auto random(const std::uniform_real_distribution<float>& dist)
    {
        static auto& RandomEngine = randomEngine();
        return dist(RandomEngine);
    }
}

class Snake : public sf::Drawable, sf::NonCopyable
{
public:
    enum Direction
    {
        None,
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right
    };

private:
    using SnakeContainer = std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>;


public:
    explicit Snake(const sf::Font& font)
    {
        reset();

        mLivesText.setFont(font);
        mLivesText.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
        mLivesText.setCharacterSize(30);
        mLivesText.setColor(sf::Color::White);
        mLivesText.setPosition(WindowSize.x - 160.f, 0.f);
    }

    void reset()
    {
        mSnakeBody.clear();
        sf::RectangleShape shape({ BlockSize - 1, BlockSize - 1 });

        shape.setPosition(70 + BlockSize, 70 + 3 * BlockSize);
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(211, 211, 211));
        mSnakeBody.push_back(shape);

        shape.setPosition(70 + BlockSize, 70 + 2 * BlockSize);
        mSnakeBody.push_back(shape);

        shape.setPosition(70 + BlockSize, 70 + BlockSize);
        mSnakeBody.push_back(shape);

        mDirection = Direction::None;
        mLives = 3;
        mLivesText.setString("Lives: " + std::to_string(mLives));
    }

    void setDirection(Direction dir)
    {
        if (mDirection == Direction::None && dir == Direction::Up)
            return;

        if (mDirection == Direction::Up && dir == Direction::Down)
            return;

        if (mDirection == Direction::Down && dir == Direction::Up)
            return;

        if (mDirection == Direction::Left && dir == Direction::Right)
            return;

        if (mDirection == Direction::Right && dir == Direction::Left)
            return;

        mDirection = dir;
    }

    bool hasLost() const
    {
        return mLives <= 0;
    }

    void lose()
    {
        mLives = 0;
    }

    void extend()
    {
        sf::RectangleShape shape({ BlockSize - 1, BlockSize - 1 });
        const auto& tail = mSnakeBody[mSnakeBody.size() - 1];

        if (mDirection == Direction::Up)
            shape.setPosition(tail.getPosition().x, tail.getPosition().y + BlockSize);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Down)
            shape.setPosition(tail.getPosition().x, tail.getPosition().y - BlockSize);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Left)
            shape.setPosition(tail.getPosition().x + BlockSize, tail.getPosition().y);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Right)
            shape.setPosition(tail.getPosition().x - BlockSize, tail.getPosition().y);

        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(211, 211, 211));
        mSnakeBody.push_back(shape);
    }

    void update()
    {
        if (mDirection == Direction::None)
            return;

        move();
        checkCollision();
    }

    sf::FloatRect getGlobalBounds() const
    {
        return mSnakeBody.front().getGlobalBounds();
    }

    bool hasCollideWithFruit(const sf::CircleShape& shape) const
    {
        for (const auto& part : mSnakeBody)
        {
            if (part.getGlobalBounds().intersects(shape.getGlobalBounds()))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


private:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override
    {
        for (const auto& part : mSnakeBody)
            target.draw(part, states);

        target.draw(mLivesText, states);
    }

    void checkCollision()
    {
        if (mSnakeBody.size() < 5)
            return;

        const auto& head = mSnakeBody.front();

        bool is_first_iteration = true;

        for (const auto& part : mSnakeBody)
        {
            if (std::exchange(is_first_iteration, false)) continue;

            if (part.getPosition() == head.getPosition())
            {
                int segments = &*(mSnakeBody.end() - 1) - &part;
                shrink(segments);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void move()
    {
        std::copy_backward(mSnakeBody.begin(), mSnakeBody.end() - 1, mSnakeBody.end());

        if (mDirection == Direction::Left)
            mSnakeBody.front().move(-BlockSize, 0);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Right)
            mSnakeBody.front().move(BlockSize, 0);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Up)
            mSnakeBody.front().move(0, -BlockSize);

        else if (mDirection == Direction::Down)
            mSnakeBody.front().move(0, BlockSize);
    }

    void shrink(int segments)
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < segments; ++i)
            mSnakeBody.pop_back();

        --mLives;

        mLivesText.setString("Lives: " + std::to_string(mLives));
    }


private:
    SnakeContainer mSnakeBody;
    Direction mDirection;
    std::size_t mLives;
    sf::Text mLivesText;
};

class World : public sf::Drawable, sf::NonCopyable
{
    using BordersContainer = std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>;
    using DistType = std::uniform_real_distribution<float>;


public:
    explicit World(const sf::Font& font)
        : mSnake(font)
        , mBorders(4)
        , mDistX(2 * BlockSize, WindowSize.x - 2 * BlockSize)
        , mDistY(3 * BlockSize, WindowSize.y - 2 * BlockSize)
        , mScore()
    {
        mFruit.setFillColor(sf::Color(211, 211, 211));
        mFruit.setRadius(BlockSize / 2.f);
        respawnFruit();

        // initial Wall borders
        for (auto& side : mBorders)
        {
            auto index = &side - &*mBorders.begin();

            if (index % 2 == 0)
                side.setSize({ WindowSize.x, BlockSize });
            else
                side.setSize({ BlockSize, WindowSize.y });

            if (index == 1)
                side.setPosition(WindowSize.x - BlockSize, 2 * BlockSize);
            else if (index == 2)
                side.setPosition(0, WindowSize.y - BlockSize);
            else
                side.setPosition(0, 2 * BlockSize);

            side.setFillColor(sf::Color(211, 211, 211));
        }

        mScoreText.setString("Score: " + std::to_string(mScore));
        mScoreText.setFont(font);
        mScoreText.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
        mScoreText.setCharacterSize(30);
        mScoreText.setColor(sf::Color::White);
        mScoreText.setPosition(30.f, 0.f);
    }

    void update(sf::Time& dt)
    {
        // real time input
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            mSnake.setDirection(Snake::Up);

        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            mSnake.setDirection(Snake::Down);

        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            mSnake.setDirection(Snake::Left);

        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            mSnake.setDirection(Snake::Right);

        if (mSnake.hasLost())
            mSnake.reset();

        if (mFruit.getGlobalBounds().intersects(mSnake.getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            mSnake.extend();
            mScoreText.setString("Score: " + std::to_string(mScore += 10));
            respawnFruit();
        }

        for (const auto& side : mBorders)
        {
            if (side.getGlobalBounds().intersects(mSnake.getGlobalBounds()))
            {
                mScore = 0;
                mScoreText.setString("Score: " + std::to_string(mScore));
                mSnake.lose();
            }
        }

        if (dt < TimeStep) return;

        dt -= TimeStep;

        mSnake.update();
    }


private:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const override
    {
        for (const auto& side : mBorders)
            target.draw(side, states);

        target.draw(mFruit, states);
        target.draw(mSnake, states);
        target.draw(mScoreText, states);
    }

    void respawnFruit()
    {
        do
            mFruit.setPosition(random(mDistX), random(mDistY));
        while (mSnake.hasCollideWithFruit(mFruit));
    }


private:
    Snake mSnake;
    sf::CircleShape mFruit;
    std::size_t mScore;
    sf::Text mScoreText;
    BordersContainer mBorders;
    DistType mDistX;
    DistType mDistY;
};

class Game : sf::NonCopyable
{
public:
    Game()
        : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(static_cast<int>(WindowSize.x), static_cast<int>(WindowSize.y)), "Snake")
        , mWorld(mFont)
    {
        if (!mFont.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
        {
            throw "Can't load font file";
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        sf::Clock clock;
        sf::Time timeElapsed = sf::Time::Zero;

        while (mWindow.isOpen())
        {
            timeElapsed += clock.restart();
            processEvents();
            update(timeElapsed);
            render();
        }
    }


private:
    void processEvents()
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                mWindow.close();
        }
    }

    void update(sf::Time& dt)
    {
        mWorld.update(dt);
    }

    void render()
    {
        mWindow.clear();
        mWindow.draw(mWorld);
        mWindow.display();
    }


private:
    sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
    World mWorld;
    sf::Font mFont;
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Game game;
        game.run();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know SFML at all, so very partial review.

```
auto random(const std::uniform_real_distribution<float>& dist)
{
    static auto& RandomEngine = randomEngine();
    return dist(RandomEngine);
}
```

There are two portability bugs here:

- `randomEngine()` returns a temporary, but `auto&` will deduce a non-const reference type here - that's an error (MSVC has an extension that accepts this though, unfortunately). But you don't need a reference here though, just a plain static object, so drop the `&`
- the distribution's `operator()(Generator &)` member is not const according to the standard. You should remove the `const` from parameter for this to be portable.

```
auto randomEngine()
{
    // ...
    thread_local std::mt19937 seeded_engine(seeds);
    // ...
}
```

This `thread_local` doesn't make sense here, at least not with your `random()` function's usage. (Even without that it's fishy, your seed manipulations would be executed on every call, but the actual engine would be constructed only once and copied out of the function.) Remove it.

If threads are involved, you need to change the `static` to `thread_local` in `random`, you'll get data races in there otherwise.

```
explicit World(const sf::Font &font)
  : mSnake(font), mBorders(4),
      mDistX(2 * BlockSize, WindowSize.x - 2 * BlockSize),
      mDistY(3 * BlockSize, WindowSize.y - 2 * BlockSize), mScore() {...}
// ...
std::size_t mScore;
// ...
DistType mDistX;
DistType mDistY;
```

The order in which you declared your variables is the order in which they will be initialized at runtime. But the order you have them in the constructor's initializer list is different. This can lead to [subtle bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222454/635608) when initialization of some members depends on others. You should make both orders match.